# How i can use the format date function

Tags: php, laravel

I have the problem when i try to format the date.

This is my view.

```
    <body>
        <h1>{{ $events->count() }} Events</h1>

        @foreach($events as $event)
            <article>
                <h1>{{ $event->name }}</h1>
                <p>{{ $event->description }}</p>
                <p>{!! format_price($event) !!}</p>
                <p>Lieu :{{ $event->location }}</p>
                <p>Date : {{ format_date($event->starts_at) }}</p>
            </article>
            @if(! $loop->last)
            <hr>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </body>
```

This is my helpers.

```
    <?php 

    function format_price($event) {
            if($event->isFree()) {
                return '<strong>GRATUIT</strong>';
            } else {
                return sprintf("%.2f euros", $event->price);
            }
        }


    function format_date($date) {
            return $date->format('d/m/y H:i');
        }


    ?>
```

This is the error that i get when i try to see the page.

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)Call to a member function format() on string (View: /home/pangraf/events/resources/views/events/index.blade.php)*

Answer (score 3):

Do use call carbon Class in laravel and pass the date you want to convert to Carbon::parse($date)->format(), learn more about carbon on [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

`$event->starts_at` is a string and not an object, use `date()` instead.
`format()` is used for DateTime objects.

```
function format_date($date) {
    return date('d/m/y H:i', strtotime($date));
}
```

Alternatively you can create an object first

```
function format_date($date) {
    $date = new DateTime($date);
    return $date->format('d/m/y H:i');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call an no existing method in a string. @spartyboy's solution is correct. 
Normally I use \Carbon\Carbon library that provides a lot of tools to manipulate dates. With carbon you can do this

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse($date)->format('d/m/y H:i');
// or Carbon:: if you declare use Carbon\Carbon; before in your code.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

> {{ format_date($event->starts_at) }}

Its Better use Carbon.

> {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($event->starts_at)->format('d/m/y H:i') }}

Or if you don't want to change go with @Qirel Answer!